# List row dividers broken by iOS 16

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, row, divider

I have a list of section headers, each with 1 or more rows.

Since updating to iOS 16 the row divider lines have been pushed to the right (as in the 1st screenshot).

[image: App running in iOS16]

When running on iOS 15.7 the row dividers are ok (as in 2nd screenshot).

[image: App running in iOS 15.7]

The minimum targeted OS for my app is iOS 15.5

Here is my code (I've only included 1st section header for brevity):

```
var videoGuideRight: CGFloat {
    switch UIDevice.current.name {
    case "iPhone SE (1st generation)", "iPod touch (7th generation)":
        return 0.18
    default:
        return 0.2
    }
}

var contactRight: CGFloat {
    switch UIDevice.current.name {
    case "iPhone SE (1st generation)", "iPod touch (7th generation)":
        return 0.04
    default:
        return 0.12
    }
}

var contactLeft: CGFloat {
    switch UIDevice.current.name {
    case "iPhone SE (1st generation)", "iPod touch (7th generation)":
        return 0.255
    default:
        return 0.27
    }
}

var contactButtonWidth: CGFloat {
    switch UIDevice.current.name {
    case "iPhone SE (1st generation)", "iPod touch (7th generation)":
            return 1/4.25
    default:
        return 1/5
    }
}

var contactFrameWidth: CGFloat {
    switch UIDevice.current.name {
    case "iPhone SE (1st generation)", "iPod touch (7th generation)":
        return 0.175
    default:
        return 0.15
    }
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Support")) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("about")
                        Text("About")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.65, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                        NavigationLink(destination: AboutView()) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image("userGuide")
                        Text("Handbook")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.65, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                        NavigationLink(destination: UserGuideView()) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image("videoGuide")
                        Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.tirnaelectronics.co.uk/polylingo-guide")!) { }
                        Spacer().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.04, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Video Guide")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3, height: 15, alignment: .leading)
                        Spacer().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * videoGuideRight, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image("contact")
                        Spacer().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * contactLeft, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Contact")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * contactFrameWidth, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                        Spacer().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * contactRight, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                        Text("E-mail")
                             .fontWeight(.bold)
                             .frame(width: screenSize.width * contactButtonWidth, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                             .font(.footnote)
                             .padding(8)
                             .background(Color.systemBlue)
                             .cornerRadius(5)
                             .foregroundColor(.white)
                             .overlay(
                                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                     .stroke(Color.systemBlue, lineWidth: 2)
                             )
                             .onTapGesture{ mailto() }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("More", displayMode: .inline).opacity(0.8)
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .background(Color.init(.systemGroupedBackground))
            
            if resetScoresPresented {
                ResetScoresAlert(isShown: $resetScoresPresented, title: "Are you sure?", message: "All test progress will be lost.  This cannot be undone!", onOK: { reset in
                    if reset {
                        resetTests()
                    }
                })
            }
            if noEmailAlertPresented {
                NoEmailAlert(showAlert: noEmailAlertPresented)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the screen shots are so bad that I can't see anything, it's just too dark and blurry.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I've changed the screenshots to light mode, and made them bigger so they don't blur.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Try to use

```
.alignmentGuide(.listRowSeparatorLeading) { _ in 0 }
```

for your sections (source: https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-list-row-separator-insets/)

Comment: See my answer to my own question. I got an explanation from Apple, but found a bodge before they replied!

Answer (score 0):

@finebel Thx for your suggestion! I got the following reply from Apple:

On iOS 16 and later, list row separators are aligned to the leading text in each row by default, if text is present. This is by design. If you'd like to override this appearance to match iOS 15 and earlier, consider using the following API, also introduced in iOS 16:

SwiftUI: HorizontalAlignment – listRowSeparatorLeading
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/horizontalalignment/listrowseparatorleading

You'll also need to use the availability attributes in Swift to ensure the project still compiles for iOS 15 as well:

The Swift Programming Language: Attributes
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html

I found a bodge by using: Text("")

So:

```
HStack {
    Text("")
    Image("\(language.name ?? "")")
    Text(language.name ?? "")
        .navigationTextFormatter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions is that you can just use the `.listRowSeparator` modifier to extend the row separator